# How can I create a POST request and retrieve it's information?

Tags: javascript, pug

So uh, I am working in a big discord bot list project and I am needing help, I am using PUGJS and Javascript, I want to post information to a specific URL in my website and retrieve it, The thing is I don't know how I can really post the request, I tried to do so using this:

routes.js

```js
router.get('/api/bots', (req, res) => {
res.send({})
});

router.get('/newbot', (req, res) => res.render('dashboard/newbot', { icon: process.env.ICON3 }))
```

newbot.pug:

```
 h1.display-5 Lenox Bot List - Add Bot
      form(action='/api/bots', method='post')
      label(for='BotID') Bot ID:
      hr
      input#team_name(type='String', value='', placeholder='Enter your Bot ID')
      hr
      input.a.button.btn.btn-success(type='submit', value='Submit bot')
```

The code didn't work when I posted to api/bots. I didn't get any ID in it.
Can someone be kind to help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a post route for creating post request

```
router.post('/api/bots', (req, res) => {
res.send({})
});
```

Additonaly you should use

> form(action='/api/bots', method='POST') in the form with capital letters

Comment: The value of the `method` attribute is case insensitive.

Comment: Maybe you are right, I used to do capital letters all time so I thought maybe this could be an issue.

Comment: Thank you sir/madam, would there be a way to get the information? I tried to going on siteurl.com/api/bots and it said there was nothing except it returned a 404 error, which meant the page was not found.